# Find and parse curl call in python (web scraping)

Tags: python, google-chrome, web, curl, screen-scraping

- I try to replay the curl calls to gather data from https://sports.admiral.at/de/livewetten/fussball?filter=all
- usually, I use the Chrome Developer Tools, recording the curl calls in the network tab
- I then proceed to use https://curlconverter.com/ and try to replay the request in Python

Unfortunately, I can't find the correct call (the response/preview in Chrome shows me only the text "1d"). Firing the curl call in python also leads to nothing useful:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'Referer': 'https://sports.admiral.at/',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
}

response = requests.post(
    'https://www.google-analytics.com/j/collect?v=1&_v=j101&aip=1&a=1569724576&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fsports.admiral.at%2Fde%2Flivewetten%2Fvideostreaming&dp=live&ul=de-de&de=UTF-8&dt=ADMIRAL%20Sportwetten%20-%20Online%20Sportwetten%20mit%20Top%20Quoten%20!%20%7C%20ADMIRAL%20Sportwetten&sd=24-bit&sr=1536x864&vp=965x722&je=0&_u=6CDAAEABAAAAACgCIAC~&jid=479555814&gjid=754274453&cid=1628183858.1688978315&tid=UA-149399994-2&_gid=680979394.1689763360&_r=1&gtm=45He37h0n81TH9JRQC&cd88=https%3A%2F%2Fsports.admiral.at%2Fde%2Flivewetten&cd13=de&cd23=sports&cd26=EUR&cd30=0&z=178536748',
    headers=headers,
)

response.json()

simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 2 - line 1 column 3 (char 1 - 2)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File line 917, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: [Errno Extra data] 1d: 1
```

What am I doing wrong - or how can I find the "correct" curl call?

Best regards!

Comment: the url you grabed from developer tools was for a analytics tracker that the original website uses.  that's not the api calls the website uses to fetch data.    you are getting a json decode error because it is in fact not json.  in developer tools, if you click on the url you can see the response data for each of the network calls and make sure it is the url you are looking for